# Neo4j Rest Api Authentication

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I'm trying to do a little program to launch a query to a neo4j DB, but it always gives me a 401 error even though I'm using URL, this is the js code.

```
    function launchQuery() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url ="http://username:password@localhost:7474/user/neo4j";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "query": "MATCH (c:Camello)-[:TRABAJA_PARA]->(:Cartel {nombre: \"Cártel de Pontón\"}) RETURN c.nombre AS Nombre, c.apellidos AS Apellido",
        "params": {}
    });
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json.Nombre + ", " + json.Apellido);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        // Add authorization header in all ajax requests
        // bmVvNGo6cGFzc3dvcmQ= is "password" base64 encoded
        "Authorization": "Basic bmVvNGo6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit ",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"statements": [{"statement": "MATCH (c:Camello)-[:TRABAJA_PARA]->(:Cartel {nombre: \"Cártel de Pontón\"}) RETURN c.nombre AS Nombre, c.apellidos AS Apellido"}]}),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       //anything on success
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```